# Is it possible to use Google Music Manager behind a proxy?

Tags: windows, google-music

I am trying using Music Manager behind a proxy but it could't connect. Is it possible to configure and use Google Music Manager on Windows 7/8 behind a proxy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of March 2014, a better solution is to enable 'Google Play Music' for Chrome:

> Install `Google Play Music' for Chrome
>   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-play-music/icppfcnhkcmnfdhfhphakoifcfokfdhg, launch it,
>   click Settings -> Lab, enable Google Play Music for Chrome and Save

~Credit: Drake.

Once done you can add music via the newly enabled browser mini-player. Goto 'My Library' and click 'Add Music'.

This completely eliminates the desktop music manager requirement. You can upload your entire music library without messing with proxifiers. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey thank you, this is a great news. Enable it is a bit tricky so maybe you can update the post. To enable this feature you have to install Google Music in Chrome (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-play-music/icppfcnhkcmnfdhfhphakoifcfokfdhg), launch it, click Settings -> Lab, enable Google Play Music for Chrome and Save Changes.

Comment: Google Play Music does not work in a virtual machine. Neither the stand alone application nor the Chrome based one.

Comment: I realize this is old but wondering if you know it is still valid. I could not find Settings -> Lab in either Chrome or the Music App. But the main menu has an Upload Music option. Do you know if it uploads only the changed or everything again when uploading existing folder?

Comment: Looks like this has been replaced with https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-play-music/fahmaaghhglfmonjliepjlchgpgfmobi/related . Unfortunately, that doesn't work behind proxies either. When I click "Launch App", I get the error "Could not connect to Google"

Answer (score 3):

Yes. For applications that don't support a proxy configuration out of the box, you need a proxifier.

There are different proxifier implementations available, but one of the most popular is *called* [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com) -- but do not confuse the application "Proxifier" as being the *only* one available, because it is not.

The essence of what a proxifier app does is, it intercepts the networking stack API calls at some level by inserting a DLL hook, whose symbols take higher precedence than the network stack. And it basically imposes the HTTP proxy by modifying the data stream before sending it to the underlying networking stack.

There may be easier ways to do this if Google Music Manager supports proxies, but I am not aware that it does.